# Best way to declare class properties in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity 3D development and I wanted to know what is the best way to declare attributes of a class to be assigned later from the editor.
I have seen mainly two:

```
public class MyObject : MonoBehavour {

    public GameObject relatedObect;

}
```

and

```
public class MyObject : MonoBehavour {
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject relatedObect;

}
```

I understand that it is of the second form because the encapsulation is maintained, but I am not sure.

Comment: these two are not equivalent, the first makes the property available to other class and the inspector, the second to the inspector only.

Comment: That's why i am asking

Comment: But thats like asking which is better apples or raspberries...  because they dont achieve the same, it isnt comparable.  as a rule you should expose as little as necessary.  So the question becomes, do you need other classes to see it or not, not really "which is best" as best is totally dependant on the requirements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please consider that in the example you declared class [fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields), and not [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties).
They are both members of a class, but they are quite different.

For the sake of this answer I'll focus on your example, so I'll talk about fields.

Both `public` and `[SerializeField] private` let you inject a value in the Unity Inspector, but they act differently in the scripts.

### 1 - public field

You declare a public field when you want it to be used or set from another class. This choice goes against encapsulation, because other script may access it. It still might be an intended behaviour if you require the field to be accessible.

### 2 - [SerializeField] private field

You use this when you want to set the item in the inspector, but you do not want the other classes to see it. This option is better for encapsulation, because in this way no other script may access or change this field.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm used to Java terminology

Comment: @Sergio Java has the EXACT same terminology, it is common across all programming languages. Java does not have properties at all, only the "getter"/"setter" pattern. Properties are a Language syntactic sugar for wrapping the "getter/setter" pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Second is the way to go if you want to do things "properly". But unfortunately there is a "bug" that throws warning on every private you set via the editor. I saw on github that it is finally getting fixed, but in the meantime if you want to remove the warning you can put your variables between `pragma warning disable 0649` and `pragma warning restore 0649`

Comment: my guess? its not a complete answer

Comment: It is also not true if you want the field to be `public` ;)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jack Mariani's answer, I want to mention `RangeAttribute` and `HideInInspectorAttribute`.

---

## `[Range (min, max)]`

If there's one, the inspector will show a slider instead of just a number. You move a slider and the value changes in specified range.

```
[SerializeField] [Range (0, 5)] private float _speed;
```

[Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RangeAttribute.html)

---

## `[HideInInspector]`

You should use it when you **do not** want a **public** variable to show up in the inspector (they are shown by default):

```
[HideInInspector] public float X;
```

[Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/HideInInspector.html)

Comment: This is not related to the question. Also there are a lot more attributes so would have to list all (actually not possible because anyone can create additional attributes) like e.g. also [`[Header("xyz")]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/HeaderAttribute.html), [`[Space]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpaceAttribute.html), [`[NonSerialized]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/NonSerialized.html), [`[AddComponentMenu]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AddComponentMenu.html), [`[TextArea]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextAreaAttribute.html) ...

Comment: @derHugo The question was about ways to access from editor. I picked those which I think are related to it. But maybe you're right.